# Запись xml в таблицу базы данных Oracle с помощью C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Пытаюсь из приложения C# записать xml-файл в таблицу Oracle в поле типа XMLTYPE. Вот код:

```
String str = "D:\\file.xml";
XmlTextWriter textWritter = new XmlTextWriter(str, Encoding.UTF8);
textWritter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
textWritter.WriteStartDocument();
textWritter.WriteStartElement("NAME");
textWritter.WriteString(TextBox1.Text);
textWritter.WriteEndElement();
textWritter.Close();
con.Open();
OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("insert into test2 (name) VALUES (test2_seq.NextVal, XMLType('<test id=\"1\"><name>Сергей</name></test>'))", con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
FillGrid();
```

Но вылетает на строчке

```
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Вот с такой вот ошибкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как поле типа XMLType может переполниться. Спасибо за помощь заранее.

Comment: @Mike вот что получилось когда попробовал заинсертить. Если знаете что не так подскажите пожалуйста. 2 обратных слэша около единички это экранирование как мне подсказали. Не пойму в чём ошибка.

Comment: Вы же вставляете только в одну колонку, зачем же test2_seq.NextVal оставили

Comment: @Mike я подумал вы мне в той теме оставили скрипт как раз готовый для вставки в поле типа XMLTYPE. Не скинете тогда сюда пример как мне нужно вставить если не сложно. И о5 же зачем там единичка и айдишник или я что то не понимаю?

Comment: Ни зачем. это я просто такую xml для теста использовал, обычный атрибут у тега. можно хоть голый `<name>Сергей</name>` использовать. Да, там он был готовый к использованию. я же вставлял в таблицу 2 поля id и xml соответственно и значений ровно два, первое для id (test2_seq.NextVal) второе для xml (XMLType(...)). Вы же сами убрали поле id из запроса, а значение для него зачем то оставили. И если бы вы вбили в гугле номер ошибки ORA-00913 то давно бы уже поняли в чем дело

Comment: @Mike понял свою ошибку переделал, но почему то теперь выдаёт missing expression Вот как выглядит сейчас `OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("insert into test2 (name) VALUES (XMLType(<name>Сергей</name>))", con);` Может быть уже совсем засмотрелся на код и не вижу банальных ошибок. Подскажите пожалуйста что я пропустил)

Comment: @Mike всё разобрался, забыл про апострофы) Бывает. Только вы не могли бы скинуть ещё раз строчку для просмотра содержимого поля XMLTYPE а то обычным селектом не выходит поглядеть. Спасибо заранее. Забыл себе сохранить когда вы мне скидывали в прошлой теме.

Comment: @Mike извините ещё раз за беспокойство и это нашёл. Если что то ещё понадобиться тогда спрашу. Спасибо ещё раз за помощь).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы хотите заполнять только поле "name", а передаете в INSERT 2 значения: test2_seq.NextVal и XMLType('Сергей')

Должно быть что то одно или указано 2 поля:

```
INSERT INTO test2 (ID, name) VALUES (test2_seq.NextVal, XMLType('<test id=\"1\"><name>Сергей</name></test>'))
```